# Best way to tell if any processes are still running on a loopfs partition?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Q: How do I fix this error, or what is the best way to do this?

Used in a function to determine if any partitions on my loopfs are still being used. Shellcheck gives an SC2276 error for this line of code:

```
"${ARRAY_PROC_LOOP[index]}"="$( lsof -e /run/user/1000/gvfs | grep 
"${ARRAY_LOOPFS[index]}" && wait )" 2>/dev/null
```

https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2276

> This is interpreted as a command name containing '='. **Bad assignment** or comparison?

Comment: `"${ARRAY_PROC_LOOP[index]}"="` is invalid. Did you mean `ARRAY_PROC_LOOP[index]="`?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you are correct.  Feeling a bit foolish at this point.